# Spring Boot Configuration

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-boot, properties-file

I have 2 applications, one using Spring inside a web-app, and another local application using Spring Boot. These 2 share a configuration class between them.

I cannot figure out how to configure the local application correctly.

Here is the basic layout of classes I am using:

The main class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class MainClass{
    @Autowired
    private static MyComponent component;

    public static void main(String args[]){
       // code
       SpringApplication.run(MyConfiguration.class, args);
       component.start(); 

    }
}
```

The configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:/path/to/queue.properties")
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    public static Environment env;
    // more beans

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("qualifier1")
    public static String getName(){ //made String and simple to match the Component's Autowired
        return env.getProperty("property.name");
    }
}
```

The component

```
@Component
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyComponent extends Thread {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("qualifier1")
    private String template; // this isn't actually String, but a springAMQP class. Should have the same effect though.

    @Override
    public void run(){
        //code
        template.charAt(0); // just something that fails if it was not autowired
        //code
    }
}
```

If .run is given `MyConfiguration.class` i get a null pointer within the autowired Environment in `MyConfiguration`. If it is given `MainClass.class` the autowired `MyComponent` is still null.

As for some layout restrictions,

the Main Class and MyComponent only exist in the local application. The Configuration is in a shared package between the local application and the web application. This prevents me from simply creating the Bean with MyComponent in the Configuration due to dependencies.

---

If I remove the MyComponent from the MainClass and add the following configuration within the Local application:

```
@Configuration
public class MyLocalConfiguration extends MyConfiguration {

    private MyComponent listener;

    @Bean
    public MyComponent getListener(){
        if(listener == null){
            listener = new MyComponent();
            listener.start();
        }
        return listener;
    }

}
```

I still have the issue of the Environment being null in MyConfiguration, preventing the other beans from being set up.

Comment: It will always be null. Your `MainClass` isn't a spring managed bean and as such will not have `@Autowired` processed. Just retrieve the bean from the context. Also why aren't you just using springs scheduling/executing support to start threads instead of hacking together your own. I would remove the `@Compoment` and add a `@Bean` declaration for the `MyComponent` class and add a `init-method` to the `@Bean` method which would call the `start` method for you. Saves you code and is easier.

Comment: just added some layout restrictions to the question. I can't make beans with MyComponent in the Configuration as i'd have to add a dependency across projects.

Comment: updated question to add LocalConfiguration in Local Application. Still having issues with Environment however

Comment: As I stated in my initial comment > It will always be null. Your `MainClass` isn't a spring managed bean and as such will not have @Autowired processed. As I also stated you really shouldn't be starting your own threads this should be left to executors and delegated to a threadpool (especially when running in a JEE container).

Comment: the `@Autowired` component isn't in the `MainClass` any more after the last change however. The `@Autowired Environment` is located in the configuration class which is Spring Managed.

Comment: Yuo cannot inject `static` fields.

Comment: removed static and it worked (Y). Post it as an answer and i'll expect it @M.Deinum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your configuration

1. `@Autowired` will only work for Spring Managed beans, your `MainClass` isn't spring managed so no autowiring is going to happen
2. `@Autowired` will not work on `static` fields